# Camera filters missing in iPhone 4s

Tags: iphone, camera

I have an iPhone 4s. My camera doesn't have the live filters at the bottom right. I went to the settings, but it doesn't have anything that says "live filters".I'm very confused and want to know how to put them on my camera.

I don't want to go to my photos app and press edit. My friends has the same phone, and they have filters.

Answer (score 1):

What version of iOS are you running? Live filters was added on iOS 7. If you haven't updated your iPhone to the latest (or, now, second-to-latest) major version of iOS, the "live" filters will not be available.
You can check your iOS version by going into Settings > General > Software Update. But, be wary of updating to iOS 8 (which is now the version available to be upgraded to) many (though not all) iPhone 4s users have had issues with iOS 8.